# efficient way to parse the file to get a List back ...?

Tags: java, groovy

```
ID Name Department Salary Designation
---------------------------------------
1  Kent Engineering 100000$ senior-engineer  
2  Smith null       50,000$ administrator
```

These are the records of a big file I have. I need to parse this file to retrieve salary and designation. The key has to be ID,Name,Department and if that fails then use ID,Name ..
I can only use Java/groovy to do this... How do I get `<Salary,Designation>` back... ?

What's the most efficient way to grep it given that i can use only java/groovy

Comment: I'm curious, is tab a separator in that file or is it more "dirty" than that? Would be really helpful to know more about the format before suggestions a potentially flawed solution.

Comment: @Pan - Have I answered your question? If so accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a BufferedReader, this will allow you to read the file one line at a time. Then call `split("[\\\s]")` on each of the lines, this will split it by whitespace.

You may also have to massage the salary field so it can be parsed into a number.

Answer (score 1):

Split each line on whitespace.

```
scala> val a = "1  Kent Engineering 100000$ senior-engineer"
a: java.lang.String = 1  Kent Engineering 100000$ senior-engineer

scala> a.split("\\s+")
res1: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, Kent, Engineering, 100000$, senior-engineer)
```

Then take the raw string values and parse those.  E.g. to convert 50,000$ into the number 50000:

```
double salary = Double.parseDouble(array[SALARY_INDEX].replaceAll("[$,]",""))


java.lang.Double.parseDouble("50,000$".replaceAll("[$,]",""))
res6: Double = 50000.0
```

Comment: And yes the examples are scala, but it should be pretty clear how to use Java instead.  It works entirely the same way, just slightly different syntax for some of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file into a `HashMap` and keep it around as long as you need it.

It has a high up-front cost, but if you're going to use it a lot, then it makes sense.

Then create your key and value objects. Be sure to override `equals` for your key.

```
public class Key{
    int id;
    String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're aware of how to read files line-by-line using a [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) as that's an obvious prerequisite for this sort of thing - if not, shout.

The key is the thing that you've failed to specify.  What, **exactly**, is the format of the data - in particular, what are the exact rules for determining where one field ends and the other begins?

If the data is separated by tab characters (and said characters are forbidden from occurring in the data, even if escaped) then the solution is simple:

```
// Ignoring general error handling and EOF-checking here
final String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
final String[] fields = line.split("\t");
```

Now you have an array containing the fields on the line, so can just look up `fields[3]` and `fields[4]`.

If the separator is "any number of spaces", and spaces are entirely disallowed, then you've got a similarly easy situation, where your regex is `line.split(" *")`.

In more complex situations, including ones where separators are allowed to appear if escaped or quoted, you may be better off simply iterating over the line character-by-character and manually building up the set of fields according to the separator rules.

Answer (score 0):

With a pinch of [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), the solution is simple and elegant. We can improve the below code by objectifying the key, handling errors etc etc but you can do that yourself

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.google.common.io.LineProcessor;

public class FileProcessor
{

    private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE);

    private static final Joiner KEY_BUILDER = Joiner.on("_").skipNulls();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Map<String, SalaryAndDesignation> result = Files.readLines(new File("c:/1.txt"), Charsets.ISO_8859_1, new LineProcessor() {

            private final Map<String, SalaryAndDesignation> result = Maps.newHashMap();

            public Object getResult()
            {
                return result;
            }

            public boolean processLine(final String line) throws IOException
            {
                Iterator<String> columns = SPLITTER.split(line).iterator();
                String id = columns.next();
                String name = columns.next();
                String dept = columns.next();

                String key = KEY_BUILDER.join(id, name, "null".equals(dept) ? null : dept);

                result.put(key, new SalaryAndDesignation(columns.next(), columns.next()));
                return true;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(result.size());
    }

    final static class SalaryAndDesignation
    {
        String salary;

        String designation;

        public SalaryAndDesignation(final String salary, final String designation)
        {
            super();
            this.salary = salary;
            this.designation = designation;
        }

    }
}
```

I see using groovy results in lesser code as sample below ([copy/pasted from here](http://snipplr.com/view/13135/reading-first-line-then-rest-of-file-line-by-line-with-eachline--gzip-support/)) but never used it myself

```
new File("simple.tab").withReader{r->
    line = r.readLine();
    println "first line: $line"
    r.splitEachLine("\t"){fields->
            println "fields on line: $fields"
    }  
}
```